# I am having trouble understanding gtk in c#

Tags: c#, gtk

Recently I started learning gtk for c#.I can't understand the placement of widgets in boxes and stuff.Like this... I wouldn't know how to add different wiidgets and place them where I want...

```
    VBox vbox = new VBox(false, 5);
    HBox hbox = new HBox(true, 3);


    Alignment valign = new Alignment(0, 1, 0, 0);

    vbox.PackStart(valign);

    Button ok = new Button("OK");
    ok.SetSizeRequest(70, 30);
    Button close = new Button("Close");

    hbox.Add(ok);
    hbox.Add(close);

    Alignment halign = new Alignment(1, 0, 0, 0);
    halign.Add(hbox);

    vbox.PackStart(halign, false, false, 3);

    Add(vbox);

    ShowAll();
```

Comment: And your question is?? Also, why use GTK when several more "native" APIs exist (Winforms, WPF, UWP, etc)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The question is there (if a little vague) - They want to know how to add and place widgets - Also, you response is a little rude - it doesn't matter why they want to use GTK, it what they need/want to learn.

Comment: @AnthonyNichols "Add and place widgets" sounds pretty broad to me (hence asking what the question/problem is). I agree that it doesn't matter why they are using it; but wanted to point out that there are easier/better solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your widgets to containers (boxes and panels) I would recommend starting with something like this:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/beginners-guide/

about 1/2 way down it talks about what you are asking for - but make sure you understand what is above it too.